# Parallelizing recursive function through MPI?

Tags: recursion, mpi

can we parallelize a recursive function using MPI?
I am trying to parallelize the quick sort function, but don't know if it works in MPI because it is recursive. I also want to know where should I do the parallel region.

```
// quickSort.c
#include <stdio.h>

void quickSort( int[], int, int);
int partition( int[], int, int);


void main() 
{
    int a[] = { 7, 12, 1, -2, 0, 15, 4, 11, 9};

    int i;
    printf("\n\nUnsorted array is:  ");
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        printf(" %d ", a[i]);

    quickSort( a, 0, 8);

    printf("\n\nSorted array is:  ");
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        printf(" %d ", a[i]);

}



void quickSort( int a[], int l, int r)
{
   int j;

   if( l < r ) 
   {
    // divide and conquer
        j = partition( a, l, r);
       quickSort( a, l, j-1);
       quickSort( a, j+1, r);
   }

}



int partition( int a[], int l, int r) {
   int pivot, i, j, t;
   pivot = a[l];
   i = l; j = r+1;

   while( 1)
   {
    do ++i; while( a[i] <= pivot && i <= r );
    do --j; while( a[j] > pivot );
    if( i >= j ) break;
    t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
   }
   t = a[l]; a[l] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
   return j;
}
```

I would also really appreciate it if there is another simpler code for the quick sort.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically you can, but I'm afraid this would be efficient only in SMP. And does the array fit to single node? If no, then you cannot perform even the first pass of a quick-sort.

If you really need to sort an array on a parallel system using MPI, you might want to consider using merge sort instead (of course you still can use quick sort for single blocks at each node, before you begin merging the blocks).

If you still want to use quick sort, but you are confused with the recursive version, here is a sketch of non-recursive algorithm which hopefully can be parallelized a bit easier, although it's essentially the same:

```
std::stack<std::pair<int, int> > unsorted;
unsorted.push(std::make_pair(0, size-1));
while (!unsorted.empty()) {
  std::pair<int, int> u = unsorted.top();
  unsorted.pop();
  m = partition(A, u.first, u.second);

  // here you can send one of intervals to another node instead of
  // pushing it into the stack, so it would be processed in parallel. 
  if (m+1 < u.second) unsorted.push(std::make_pair(m+1, u.second));
  if (u.first < m-1) unsorted.push(std::make_pair(u.first, m-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically "anything" can be parallelized using MPI, but remember that MPI isn't doing any parallelization itself. It's just providing the communication layer between processes. As long as all of your sends and receives (or collective calls) match up, it's a correct program for the most part. That being said, it may not be the most efficient thing to use MPI, depending on your algorithm. If you are going to be sorting lots and lots of data (more than can fit in the memory of one node) then it could be efficient to use MPI (you probably want to take a look at the RMA chapter in that case) or some other higher level library that might make things even simpler for this type of application (UPC, Co-array Fortran, SHMEM, etc.).